# How can I pass this case rule in Scala to only accept string containing letters?

Tags: regex, scala

I'm working on learning Scala through the Exercism exercises and am stuck on the Bob exercise. My goal in the second to last case is to answer Whoa, chill out! if a given statement has capital letters but can also contain anything else aside from a question mark. I can't seem to find a way to achieve this without contradicting another rule. I'm not sure if isLetter is an actual function but my Exercism mentor suggested I use it.

```
object Bob {
  def response(statement: String): String = {
//  println(statement)
  println("k".contains("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray))
  statement.trim() match {
    case x if x.isEmpty => "Fine. Be that way!"
    case x if x.matches("^[A-Z0-9][^a-z].+\\?$") => "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
    case x if x.matches("^.+\\?$") => "Sure."
    case x if (x.matches ("[A-Z %\\^*@#$(*\\!,)0-9]+") /*&& x.isLetter*/) => "Whoa, chill out!"
    case _ => "Whatever."
  }
  }

}
```

The test cases I'm running into trouble with:

```
"1, 2, 3 GO!"
"1, 2, 3"
```

1, 2, 3 GO! should be who, chill out.
Whereas 1, 2, 3 should be whatever but always returns as whoa chill out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why the one with GO should match and the other one not?

Comment: who wrote those regex's ? Are they part of the problem statement or your solution ? Can you also provide your problem statement and not just your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

From the limited explanation provided, I think that the "Whoa..." case is supposed to check for two conditions,

1. Presense of at least 1 captital letter.
2. Question mark can not be present at any place at all.

If these are your requirements then your "Whoa..." case can be simply written as an AND of these two conditions.

```scala
case x if (x.matches("(.*)([A-Z]+)(.*)") && !x.matches("(.*)(\\?)(.*)")) => "Whoa, chill out!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single pattern with a positive lookahead asserting a char A-Z, and then matching any char except a question mark.

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z\n])[^?\n]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that on the right is

  - `[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z]` Match any char other than a newline or A-Z, then match A-Z
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^?\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than `?` or a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcsLkS/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/thhige)

For example

```
object Bob {
  def response(statement: String): String = {
    statement.trim() match {
      case x if x.isEmpty => "Fine. Be that way!"
      case x if x.matches("^[A-Z0-9\\n][^a-z].+\\?$") => "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
      case x if x.matches("^.+\\?$") => "Sure."
      case x if x.matches ("^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[^?\\n]+$") => "Whoa, chill out!"
      case _ => "Whatever."
    }
  }
}

Bob.response("1, 2, 3 GO!")
Bob.response("1, 2, 3")
```

Output

```
val res0: String = Whoa, chill out!
val res1: String = Whatever.
```